# where do i put a while loop?

Tags: visual-c++, while-loop

In an English class, a student is given 4 term tests (each marked out of 50) and one final exam (marked
out of 100). Each term test is weighted at 20% of the overall mark for the course and the final exam
is also weighted at 20%. Write a program to read marks for the 4 term tests followed by the mark for
the final exam. The program then printsthe final overall mark as well asthe grade. The grading scheme
follows. **A (75-100), B (60-74), C (50-59), F (under 50).**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if (infile.is_open())
        cout<<"File is opened"<<endl;
    else{
        cout<<"Unable to open file"<<endl;
        exit (1);
    }


    int id, test1,  test2, test3, test4, final1; 
    infile>>id>>test1>>test2>>test3>>test4>>final1;

    float tests, finals, grade;
     tests = ((test1+test2+test3+test4)/200.0)*80;
     finals= (final1/100.0)*20;
     grade= tests+finals;
 
cout<<"ID"<<"\t"<<"%"<<"\t"<<"Grade"<<endl;
     if(grade>=75)
        cout<<id<<"\t"<<grade<<"\t"<<"A"<<endl;
    else if(grade>=60)
        cout<<id<<"\t"<<grade<<"\t"<<"B"<<endl;
    else if(grade>=50)
        cout<<id<<"\t"<<grade<<"\t"<<"C"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<id<<"\t"<<grade<<"\t"<<"F"<<endl;


   infile>>id>>test1>> test2>>test3>>test4>>final1;

    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: the first data line is:
1582 20 10 15 30 60
where 1582 is the student ID, 20, 10, 15, 30 are the term test marks and 60 is the final exam mark.

Comment: You put your while loop around the code that needs to loop. I think your assignment wants you to figure out where that is and how to write it.

Comment: I've amssumed that the while loop goes around the if statements however that causes an infinite looping. I've tried placing it after the infile reading but that causes an error for some reason.